# How to refresh table of parent window from childwindow using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to refresh just table of parent window from child window When I use this:

```
 $('#mytable').load('page.php');
```

The script is showing parent page in child window.
I want to refresh parent window, when I click save button child window.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. When you use load. you do not have a "child" window. Also if you want to refresh a table, you should load a div with a div: `$('#mytableContainerDiv').load('page.php #mytableContainerDiv');`

Comment: @ mplungjan u mean div id will be include in script not table id?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If there is a div in page.php with the ID mytableContainerDiv, then that div will be loaded into the target div

Comment: I want to refresh this div in parent window by using child window.Dont want to show this div in child window

Comment: What do you mean by child window. Does the parent window open a new popup window using window.open?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh parent window.

```
opener.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

What would be a better approach is that we wrap the initial command in a function and pass it in child's scope and call it from there -:

```
function init(){
    $('#mytable').load('page.php');
}
```

Either pass this function in child scope or attach this function in `window` or any global object and use it from child scope.